# Randomizing Square colors

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have four squares on my screen and I want each of the squares to display a different image every time for each square. I have got it to work, but as the code repeats sometimes there is a delay. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my main code

```
   #import "HomeScreenViewController.h"

@interface HomeScreenViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeScreenViewController

-(void)startRandomSquares
{

    self.greenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenSquare.png"];
    self.redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedSquare"];
    self.blueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueSquare"];
    self.purpleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PurpleSquare"];

    self.arrayOfColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.greenImage,self.redImage, self.blueImage, self.purpleImage, nil];

}
-(IBAction)Button1:(id)sender
{
    self.startLabel.hidden = YES;
}
-(IBAction)Button2:(id)sender
{

}
-(IBAction)Button3:(id)sender
{

}
-(IBAction)Button4:(id)sender
{

}

-(void)randomizeAllSquares
{
    [self randomizedSquare1];
    [self randomizedSquare2];
    [self randomizedSquare3];
    [self randomizedSquare4];
}

-(void)randomizedSquare1
{

    [self startRandomSquares];

    randomColor = arc4random() % [self.arrayOfColors count];
    square1RandomNumber = randomColor;


   // NSLog(@"Square 1 : %d", square1RandomNumber);
    //NSLog(@"Square 1 colors : %@", self.arrayOfColors);

    switch (square1RandomNumber) {
        case 0:
            self.square1.image = self.arrayOfColors[0];
            break;

        case 1:
            self.square1.image = self.arrayOfColors[1];
            break;
        case 2:
           self.square1.image = self.arrayOfColors[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.square1.image = self.arrayOfColors[3];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    if (square1RandomNumber == square2RandomNumber ) {
        [self randomizedSquare1];
        NSLog(@"Square 1-2 MATCH!!!");
    }
    if (square1RandomNumber == square4RandomNumber) {
        [self randomizedSquare1];
        NSLog(@"Square 1-4 Match!!!");
   }

}

-(void)randomizedSquare2
{
    [self startRandomSquares];


    randomColor = arc4random() % [self.arrayOfColors count];
    square2RandomNumber = randomColor;


     //NSLog(@"Square 2 : %d", square2RandomNumber);
    //NSLog(@"Square 2 colors : %@", self.arrayOfColors);

    switch (square2RandomNumber) {
        case 0:
            self.square2.image = self.arrayOfColors[0];
            break;

        case 1:
            self.square2.image = self.arrayOfColors[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.square2.image = self.arrayOfColors[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.square2.image = self.arrayOfColors[3];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (square2RandomNumber == square1RandomNumber ) {
        [self randomizedSquare2];
        NSLog(@"Square 2-1 Match!!!");
    }
    if (square2RandomNumber == square4RandomNumber) {
        [self randomizedSquare2];
        NSLog(@"Square 2-4 Match!!!");
    }

}

-(void)randomizedSquare3
{
    [self startRandomSquares];

    randomColor = arc4random() % [self.arrayOfColors count];
    square3RandomNumber = randomColor;

    //NSLog(@"Square 3 : %d", square3RandomNumber);
    //NSLog(@"Square 3 colors : %@", self.arrayOfColors);

    switch (square3RandomNumber) {
        case 0:
            self.square3.image = self.arrayOfColors[0];
            break;

        case 1:
            self.square3.image = self.arrayOfColors[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.square3.image = self.arrayOfColors[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.square3.image = self.arrayOfColors[3];
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
    if (square3RandomNumber == square2RandomNumber  ){
        [self randomizedSquare3];
        NSLog(@"Square 3 - 2 MATCH!!!");
    }
    if (square3RandomNumber == square1RandomNumber) {
        [self randomizedSquare3];
        NSLog(@"Square 3- 1 MATCH!!");
    }

}
-(void)randomizedSquare4
{
    [self startRandomSquares];

    randomColor = arc4random() % [self.arrayOfColors count];
    square4RandomNumber = randomColor;

    //NSLog(@"Square 4 : %d", square4RandomNumber);
    //NSLog(@"Square 4 colors : %@", self.arrayOfColors);

    switch (square4RandomNumber) {
        case 0:
            self.square4.image = self.arrayOfColors[0];
            break;

        case 1:
            self.square4.image = self.arrayOfColors[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.square4.image = self.arrayOfColors[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.square4.image = self.arrayOfColors[3];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    if (square4RandomNumber == square2RandomNumber ) {
        [self randomizedSquare4];
        NSLog(@"Square 4-2 MATCH!!");
}
    if (square4RandomNumber == square1RandomNumber) {
        [self randomizedSquare4];
        NSLog(@"SQuare 4-1 MATCH!!");
    }
    if (square4RandomNumber == square3RandomNumber) {
        [self randomizedSquare4];
        NSLog(@"Square 4-3 Match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ouch, that's a lot of code duplication.  In general if you find yourself writing a similar piece of code multiple times it's not just best practice to generalize it, but you'll likely end up with a better solution.

A simple shuffle function on your array along with a simple reassign would work, and will give a runtime of N (ie the loop will only go through the array once per call).  What you have now will technically try to create the color for a square multiple times in the case that it finds a match which is the reason for your slowness.  Square 4 has a 3/4 chance that it will get the same color as another square so it likely runs at least 3 times before stopping.

```
- (void)shuffleImages
{
    //uses the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
    for (NSUInteger i = self.arrayOfColors.count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int index = arc4random_uniform(i+1);
        [self.arrayOfColors exchangeObjectAtIndex:index withObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

- (void)updateImages
{
    [self shuffleImages];
    self.square1.image = self.arrayOfColors[0];
    self.square2.image = self.arrayOfColors[1];
    self.square3.image = self.arrayOfColors[2];
    self.square4.image = self.arrayOfColors[3];
}
```

All you need to do when you want your colors to change is call the updateImages function.

Comment: Okay i called the updateImages function in my randomizeSquare functions but there is still a tiny delay occasionally is that fixable or do i just have to deal with it?

Comment: That's a tough question to answer without seeing the rest of your project, however the shuffle and assign approach is as fast (in terms of computational complexity) as your going to get.  At this point I would look into using instruments to see what else the culprit might be.

Answer (score 0):

The delay comes from the check at the end of each randomisation. There's a 75% chance the number generated is in one of the other 3 squares, so it will loop and loop until it generates the only number it can be.

A better solution would be to shuffle the array of images, and then assign each image to each view in order.

e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
shuffle array of images

view 1 = array[0]
view 2 = array[1]
...
view 4 = array[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Brandon is right about the insane amount of code duplication, and using the fischer-yates algorithm is definitely the right way to go, but it sounds like you also want this to repeat, so you should use an `NSTimer`.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *randomizeColorTimer;`

```
- (void)startRandomizing
{
    _randomizeColorTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(shuffleImages)
                                                          userInfo:nil
                                                           repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopRandomizing
{
    [_randomizeColorTimer invalidate];
    _randomizeColorTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes I had a timer to repeat it, i just didnt add it to the post since and sorry for the amount of code